# Subclass Objective-C class without linking with the superclass?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, objective-c-runtime, cydia-substrate, simbl

I'm writing a [SIMBL](https://github.com/norio-nomura/EasySIMBL) plugin for Spotlight, and I'm trying to create a subclass of an internal Spotlight type. While I can get headers directly from the executable using [class-dump](http://stevenygard.com/projects/class-dump/), I don't have a static library to link against, so compiling a subclass of one of those internal classes fails (even though the classes will be available at runtime). I've been following Mike Ash's instructions on [subclassing classes at runtime](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-11-19-creating-classes-at-runtime-for-fun-and-profit.html), but it's pretty inconvenient. Is there any way to create a subclass of an Objective-C class without the superclass being available at link time?

Comment: `NSClassFromString()` and `objc_allocateClassPair()` are your friends. No, it's not going to be as convenient as doing it at compile-time.

Comment: Ahh, alas. I was hoping there was a simpler way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is entirely possible, and not actually very difficult to do. Here's a simple example with NSValue:

```
@interface MySubclass : NSObject

-(void) someMethod;

@end

@implementation MySubclass

+(void) load {
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated"

    class_setSuperclass(self, NSClassFromString(@"NSValue"));

#pragma clang diagnostic pop
}

-(void) someMethod {
    NSLog(@"%@", [self superclass]);
}

-(const char *) objCType {
    return @encode(int);
}

-(void) getValue:(void *)value {
    if (value) {
        *((int *) value) = 10;
    }
}

@end

int main() {
    MySubclass *theSubclass = [MySubclass new];
    [theSubclass someMethod];

    NSLog(@"%i", [theSubclass isKindOfClass:[NSValue class]]);
}
```

`class_setSuperclass`, while deprecated, still has an implementation as of OS X 10.10, and *can* be done after the class has been registered. I have not fully explored the effects of changing a class's superclass post the creation of an instance of that class, however, so take caution if you are to do this at any point past `+load` or `+initialize`.

This may make it difficult to call methods on `super`, but this could be gotten around by simply declaring a category on `NSObject` (or whichever superclass you choose to inherit from in your implementation).